# Botframework dynamically call dialog from reusable dialog

Tags: c#, botframework

Let's say, for example, that we have a `LoginDialog` (reusable dialog) that is called at different times to access specific areas/dialogs of your bot.

Being a reusable dialog, you don't want to write explicit call of child dialog.

```
public class LoginDialog : IDialog<object> {

public async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context) {
    var message = "Insert password";

    PromptDialog.Text(context, AfterPassword,
            message,
            null,
            1);
}

public async Task AfterPassword(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<string> result) {
        var password = await result;
        var valid = await Mocks.ValidatePasswordMockAsync(password);

        if (valid) {
    context.Call(new TheDialog(), ResumeAfter);
        } else context.Call(new TransferDialog(), ResumeAfter);
    }

private async Task ResumeAfter(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result) {
        context.Done<object>(null);
    }}
```

Maybe you have more than one dialogs that need login validation.

What you want to do is to use reflection in order to reuse that dialog?

I tried something like this:

```
public class LoginDialog : IDialog<object> {

    private string classToCall;

    public LoginDialog(string classToCall) {
        this.classToCall = classToCall;
    }

    public async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context) {
        var message = "Insert password";

        PromptDialog.Text(context, AfterPassword, message, null, 1);
    }

    public async Task AfterPassword(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<string> result) {
        var password = await result;
        var valid = await Mocks.ValidatePasswordMockAsync(password);

        if (valid) {
            var type = Type.GetType(classToCall);
            context.Call(Activator.CreateInstance(type), ResumeAfter);
        } 
        else 
            context.Call(new TransferDialog(), ResumeAfter);
    }

    private async Task ResumeAfter(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result) {
        context.Done<object>(null);
    }
}
```

I get an error on this line:

```
context.Call(Activator.CreateInstance(type), ResumeAfter);
```

> Type arguments cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

What do you recommend? A forced cast (as `IDialog<object>`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of delegating the responsibility of calling the next dialog to the `LoginDialog`, wouldn't be better to make the `LoginDialog` to return if it's valid or not, and have the caller decide who to call next?

Regarding your issue, first, check if the `Type.GetType` is returning what you expected and then yes, try casting to see if the issue is there or if there is something else going on.

Comment: You are right on both.
First, regarding the issue, I made a bubu on GetType.
Now I use Func<IDialog<object>> and I call it like this: new LoginDialog(() => new TheDialog())

Second, you are absolutely right and I never thought of this. I will return from login dialog the result and decide next dialog outside.